# Does jQuery serialize() guarantee data from form is ordered?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a series of input that represents different forms:

```
<form id="myform">

    <div id="item1">
        <label> Name </label><input name="item1" type="text" value=""/>
    </div>

    <div id="item2">
        <label> Name </label><input name="item2" type="text" value=""/>
    </div>

    <div id="item3">
        <label> Name </label><input name="item3" type="text" value=""/>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
     $.post("/url/", $("#myform").serialize(), function(){});
</script>
```

When the post happens, is it guaranteed that I'll receive the data the order it is presented in the form? I've tested it and it does return the item1, item2, item3 in that order, but is it safe to assume that?

Comment: Mind if I ask why order matters?

Comment: No, you can't assume that. Why do you need it in an order?

Comment: @j08691: It's not uncommon to have a series of parallel fields (x/y, x/y, x/y) and want to associate them by their order.

Comment: Are you not going to name your input fields, and just assume information is going to be entered in the order you need?

Comment: `$("#myform").serialize()` won't actually do anything since none of your inputs have `name` attributes.

Comment: @RagingCelt Sorry, it was just some quick random html I wrote up. I've added that in.

Comment: Before HTML5 not even _HTML_ did guarantee an order (as far as I can see), so you should not rely on it for any purposes IMHO. As for @T.J.Crowder’s interjection – well that could be fixed by naming the fields in a way that allows to correlate them server-side (for processing them in PHP that could f.e. be `x[0]`,`y[0]`,`x[1]`,`y[1]`, etc.)

Comment: @CBroe: That the fields are sent in document order when using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` has been specified since 1995 or thereabouts, originally in a combination of [RFC 1867](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt) and the [HTML 3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#form) spec referring to it; then HTML 4 [goes further](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-content-type), putting the specification of document order in the HTML spec as well as the RFC. And as you say, that was carried on in HTML5.

Comment: Thanks, wasn’t aware that this was specified for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in detail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a tricky question. [The `serialize` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) doesn't say anything about order, but *does* say:

> ...creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation.

The RFC for that notation, [RFC 1867](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt), states:

> Each field of the form is sent, in the order in which it occurs in the form, as a part of the multipart stream.

Empirical results using [a really old version](http://jsbin.com/lowoqaha/1) of jQuery (v1.2.1) and [the current version](http://jsbin.com/lowoqaha/2) (v1.11.0) both show the order being preserved.

So I would say even though the *jQuery* documentation isn't explicit about it, its reference to "standard URL-encoded notation" combined with the RFC and the stabiilty of the behavior indicates you can rely on it. If it were to change (which seems *very* unlikely, jQuery in general does things in document order), I'd think it could reasonably be considered a bug.

Answer (score 2):

The general rule of thumb is that if an API doesn't specify the behavior in its documentation or explicitly demonstrate a behavior in some other way, then you shouldn't rely on it behaving that way, even if tests show that it does and even if the source code shows that it does.

In this case, it would appear that ordering is preserved and there's nothing in the source code that shows that it doesn't, but there is nothing mentioned in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) so I would caution against depending on that behavior.  There is no guarantee that it'll stay that way, since it's only coincidental, and if another developer (including you 6 months from now) has to go back to that code, they'll most likely not recognize that your requirements expect it to be ordered and possibly introduce regression errors (or just get pissed off at you for using a 'hack' and make you buy them a beer)

Answer (score 1):

Never rely on data being ordered. If you want to give it some sort of order, you can specify the post variables on the form as field[0], field [1] and use the key to enforce the field order.